# ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list in Python

Tags: python

This is my code

```
lower = int(input('pleace input the beggest num：'))
upper = int(input('pleace input the smallest num：'))
lis=[]
for num in range(lower,upper):
    lis.append(num)
    for i in range(2,num-1):
        if num%i == 0:
            lis.remove(num) 
print(lis)
```

Which stop is wrong?

Comment: Rather than add and immediately remove a composite number, why not just wait until you determine that `num` is prime before adding it to `lis`?

Comment: The upper limit of `range` is *exclusive* so you probably need `range(lower, upper +1 )`.

Comment: I have try to changed the upper,when it <=6,it'ok

Comment: @ fsimonjetz it's not work

Comment: @东海岛礁 Indeed, that's not the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this programme is to find all primes between [lower, upper).
And the problem in your code is that you should break the loop when you find `x` is not prime. such as:

```
if num%i == 0:
    lis.remove(num)
    break
```

Comment: It's a good idea and it's worked!

Answer (score 1):

If there is a number that’s divisible by more than one number from `range(2,num-1)`, your program will try to remove it multiple times, but that value wouldn’t be there after it’s removed the first time.

For example, let’s consider number 6. You add it to your list, then, in the `for` loop, you go from 2 to 4 (mind you, `range` excludes the upper limit!). `6 % 2 == 0`, so your `if` statement is true, so you remove that six from the list… but the loop continues. Then, it checks for 3, and `6 % 3 == 0`, too, so it tries to call `lis.remove(6)`… but that six is no longer there—you’ve removed it beforehand.

In the future, consider using a debugger for running your programs step-by-step, it will help you find your errors.